# Import data, analyze spatially, and export list of points using Google Earth

Tags: export, import, overlay, select-by-location, google-earth-pro

I am trying to:

1. import data into Google Earth from an outside data source.
2. Then overlay a map and isolate which datapoints fall into that area.
3. I would like to then export a list of the data points to give to a person that works with our company.

Can I do this in Google Earth Pro?  Can you direct me to a resource that would walk me through this?  Is there a better solution for doing this type of work if it can't?

Comment: What are you using Google Earth for? Just for the imagery, or is there something else I'm missing? You may want to look into QGIS (it's free) and can definitely do what you want it to - however you'd have to find your own imagery/raster for the specific area

Comment: @GISKid - Well we started with google earth as one of the overlays we are doing are shakemaps from the USGS website which are provided in KML. They also have hazus and shape files for them as well. I started with Google Earth as the KML file was the only one I was familiar with.  I will check out the QGIS if it is an option - the data I am importing is private, so I cannot use any server style programs if that helps narrow the results.

Comment: You can definitely import KML with most gis programs (ArcGIS being popular but proprietary, QGIS being free) See the guide for QGIS here http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/import_kml.php

Comment: My fear on using other programs is that I will have to have them vetted through our IT department.  We already have access to Google Earth Pro for other business needs, so I was hoping to find a way to do the same thing in that software.  It appears that from reviewing the QGIS site, I am looking to find a "spatial join" feature within Google Earth.  My fear, based on research, is that this is not easily achieved in Google Earth.  Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that or those sort of tasks in Google Earth. Your best investment would be QGIS. Use the [OSGEO Network Installer](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) if you can.

The process you will use depends on the format of the map that you propose to overlay. Is it another vector layer? If so, is it a complete polygon or just a line which encloses the area of interest. For a one off analysis, you might just use a clipper tool.

Comment: I think Google Earth Pro might be OK for 1 & 3 depending on the format requirements but it is 2 which would cause it more drama.